# how to assign extra hidden parameter to individual bars of Jqplot bar chart/Pie chart

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I want to pass additional hidden parameters to individual bars or pie slice of Jqplot  chart. Actually, i want that when i click on the individual bars/slice then it should take me to different page depend on the keys assign to each bars/slice. Right now, onClick event i can capture data, gridpos etc. But here i want to attach key values to bars/slice and should be able to access these keys when click on bars/slice.
Could someone please point me how to do this?

Here is the jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/jdev/4e9Ls/39/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing stopping you from adding addtional parameters in the data array:

```
var data = [
         ["USD",5000,"Hello"], ["CAD",2000, "I"], ["JPY",10000, "Am"], ["AUD",9000, "Additional"]
];
```

And then in the click event:

```
$('#chart2').bind('jqplotDataClick', function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) { 
    alert(data[2]);
});
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4e9Ls/53/).

Comment: Thanks Mark.This is what i am looking for. However, for bar chart when i add third parameter then chart displays label as third parameter instead of second. I want that it display second parameter on top of bar and via third param i just wanted to pass keys. here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jdev/sQmEx/9/

Comment: It looks like it takes the last param in that array for the point label.  So you could keep hacking it and duplicate them: http://jsfiddle.net/sQmEx/10/